# Laptop WiFi speed drops

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

- Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad SL510
- Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS (64-bit)

---

Sometimes with no reasons, WiFi internet speed drops to minimum. And if I reconnect to this wireless network, speed becomes normal again, but only for few minutes, then speed drops again. This problem appears and disappears without any obvious reasons.

It's not WiFi problem, because speed is fine on second laptop (Win10) and on four phones.

---

Terminal results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; iwconfig`:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:2131]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FigVam"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: F4:F2:6D:B2:83:34   
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:64  Invalid misc:2667   Missed beacon:0

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: It could be a WiFi not having the recommended wireless encryption settings, at the router: WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Adjust and try again.

Comment: Please edit the question to include terminal results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; iwconfig`

Comment: @CelticWarrior, I have "Auto" there. I need to change it to `WPA2-AES`?
@Jeremy31, updated.

Comment: "Auto" is usually where problems start... ;)

Comment: `11n` should be disable to get this chip work well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling wifi power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot